# regcomp() ошибка компиляции выражения

Tags: c, регулярные-выражения

Доброго времени суток.
Имею следующие регулярные выражения (и C код их компилирующий). Не могу понять, что regcomp'у не нравится. Но, я как бы не спец в таковых. Так по-верхам нахватался (в код ниже внесены изменения, в связи с обновлением вопроса. исходные ошибочные строки регулярок, перемещены в комментарии соответствующих строк кода)

```
static const char* dig_sym_re[2] = {
  "\\{symbol-(\\d+):(\\d|direct)\\}" // "{symbol-(\\d+):(\\d+|direct)}"
  ,"\\{digit-(\\d+):(\\d|direct)\\}" // "{digit-(\\d+):(\\d+|direct)}"
};

int somefunc()
{
  . . .
  for( i=0; i<2; i++ )
  {
    regex_t regex;
    regmatch_t match[3];
    p = tmpl->text;
    if (regcomp( &regex, dig_sym_re[i], REG_EXTENDED )) 
    {
      fprintf(stderr, "Could not compile regex: %s\n", dig_sym_re[i]);
      exit(1);
    }
    while( 0 == regexec( &regex, p, 3, match, 0 ) )
    {
      . . .
    }
    regfree(&regex);
  }
  . . .
}
```

Спасибо Sergey, после добавления "\" перед фигурными скобками стало компилироваться. (далее скопировано из моего комментария под его ответом)
И если данное выражение скормить, например, в поиске по регулярному выражению, то оно даже работает. Но в моем коде, почему-то ничего не находит. видимо что-то не так делаю.  задача выискивать в исходном тексте такие блоки: {digit-128:4}  или {symbol-96:direct}. Т.е. после тире идет число, а после двоеточия число или слово direct. В исходном коде, в вопросе исправил строки с регулярками, поставив некорректные в комментарий. И добавил regex().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ваше регулярное выражение выглядит довольно странно... Возникают вопросы:

1. Конструкция в фигурных скобках называется интервальным квантификатором. Вы действительно это имели в виду? Но тогда перед открывающей скобкой должен быть повторяемый символ. Его нет!
2. Что такое "digit" в Вашем выражении ? Может быть Вы имели в виду выражение [:digit:] -  цифры в RE ?

Если Ваше RE записать так:

```
"\\{symbol-(\\d+):(\\d+|direct)\\}",                                                                        
"\\{digit-(\\d+):(\\d+|direct)\\}"
```

то компиляция RE проходит. Но я не уверен, что Вы имели в виду.

По поводу Ваших исправлений. У меня вызывает сомнение один момент - а что за строку Вы пытаетесь парсить ?

Перепишите этот цикл

```
while( 0 == regexec( &regex, p, 3, match, 0 ) )
    {
      . . .
    }
```

Как то так:

```
int rc;
while(1) {
    rc = regexec( &regex, p, 3, match, 0 );
    if ( rc == 0 ) {
       // Нормальная обработка
    } else {
      printf("Ошибка %d\n", rc);
      printf("'%s'", p);
      break;
    }
}
```

Любопытно посмотреть на причину ошибки и анализируемый текст.

Comment: похоже что так. доберусь до того компа, проверю. просто где-то наткнулся, и там рекомендовали убрать слеш перед фигурными скобками.спасибо.

Comment: добавление перед фигурными скобками "\\" помогло, с тем что не компилируется. и если данное выражение скормить, например, в поиске по регулярному выражению, то оно даже работает. Но в моем коде, почему-то ничего не находит. видимо что-то не так делаю.  задача выискивать в исходном тексте такие блоки: {digit-128:4}  или {symbol-96:direct}. после тире идет число, а после двоеточия число или слово direct

Comment: обновил исходный код и добавил в вопрос свой комментарий выше